# Multiple persists in the Spark Execution plan

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I currently have some spark code (pyspark), which loads in data from S3 and applies several transformations on it. The current code is structured in such a way that there are a few persists along the way in the following format

```
df = spark.read.csv(s3path)
df = df.transformation1
df = df.transformation2
df = df.transformation3
df = df.transformation4
df.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)

df = df.transformation5
df = df.transformation6
df = df.transformation7
df.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
.
.
.
df = df.transformationN-2
df = df.transformationN-1
df = df.transformationN
df.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

When I do df.explain() at the very end of all transformations, as expected, there are multiple persists in the execution plan. Now when I do the following at the end of all these transformations

```
print(df.count())
```

All transformations get triggered, including the persist. Since spark will flow through the execution plan, it will execute all these persists. Is there any way that I can inform Spark to unpersist the N-1th persist, when performing the Nth persist, or is Spark smart enough to do this. My issue stems from the fact that later on in the program, I run out of disk space, ie, spark errors out with the following error:

`No space left on device`

An easy solution is of course to increase the underlying number of instances. But my hypothesis is that the high number of persists eventually costs the disk to go out of space.

My question is, do these donkey persists cause this issue? If they do, what is the best way/practice to structure the code so that I can unpersist the N-1th persist automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm more experienced with Scala Spark but it's definitely possible to unpersist a Dataframe.

In fact, the [Pyspark method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html) of a Dataframe is also called `unpersist`. So in your example, you could do something like (this is quite crude):

```
df = spark.read.csv(s3path)
df = df.transformation1
df = df.transformation2
df = df.transformation3
df = df.transformation4
df.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)

df1 = df.transformation5
df1 = df1.transformation6
df1 = df1.transformation7
df.unpersist()
df1.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
.
.
.
dfM = dfM-1.transformationN-2
dfM = dfM.transformationN-1
dfM = dfM.transformationN
dfM-1.unpersist()
dfM.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

Now, the way this code looks triggers some questions in me. It might be that you've mostly written this as pseudocode to be able to ask this question, but still maybe the following questions might help you further:

- I only see transformations in there, and no actions. If this is the case, do you even need to persist?
- Also, you only seem to have 1 source of data (the `spark.read.csv` bit): this also seems to hint at not necessarily needing to persist.
- This is more of a point about style (and maybe opinionated, so don't worry if you don't agree). As I said in the beginning, I have no experience with Pyspark but the way that I would write (in Scala Spark) something similar to what you have written would be something like this:

```
df = spark.read.csv(s3path)
       .transformation1
       .transformation2
       .transformation3
       .transformation4
       .persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)

df = df.transformation5
       .transformation6
       .transformation7
       .persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
.
.
.
df = df.transformationN-2
       .transformationN-1
       .transformationN
       .persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

This is less verbose and IMO a little more "true" to what really happens, just a chaining of transformations on the original dataframe.